# TypeError: Undefined is not an object this.prop

Tags: javascript, java, ios, reactjs, react-native

Receiving an error TypeError: Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.track[this.state.selectedTrack]')

when trying run my simulator for iOS. I am building player. the error I am receiving when I start it up is below . and the code will be right under that for the player

any guidance will be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Player as PodCast} from './PodcastLayers/Player';

export const TRACKS = [
{
title: 'Stressed Out',
artist: 'Twenty One Pilots',
albumArtUrl: "http://36.media.tumblr.com/14e9a12cd4dca7a3c3c4fe178b607d27/tumblr_nlott6SmIh1ta3rfmo1_1280.jpg",
audioUrl: "http://russprince.com/hobbies/files/13%20Beethoven%20-%20Fur%20Elise.mp3",
},
];

export default class PodCastScreen extends React.Component {
render() {
return <PodCast tracks={TRACKS}/>
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that `this.props.tracks`is a problem because you are trying to set an object to something that hasn't been declared yet.

You pass in a prop for tracks. I think the usage is kinda wrong too.

Comment: Above is correct, where is this.props.tracks coming from?

Comment: @Demon so I declared it and now I am getting the error above, the imports are right.

Comment: What is Podcast module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second problem that you posted, you should import the class  `PodCastScreen` as `import PodCastScreen from'./PodcastLayers/Player';`

Answer (score 1):

2 state might be happening:

1. you are not passing "track" in your props
2. you are passing "track" with null or undefined value

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. It could also be that he hasn't declared tracks as a prop yet.